# Xcode 4 code backward compatible

Tags: xcode4, xcode3.2

Can I create code on Xcode4 and then run this exact same code on Xcode3. In other words is it backward compatible and if not what do I have to do to ensure that I can run the code on xcode 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run the same code in XCode 3 assuming you haven't used features available in newer SDKs, not available in older XCode version.

But as @drekka said, project format will be most likely incompatible between two versions, so you'll probably need to ignore XCode 4 project upgrade warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Not something I've tried. You need to check the Project Format is set to the matching Xcode 3 version. But I would still not be surprised if it didn't work. The reality is that this is Xcode's way of telling you to update your XCode 3 machine :-)

BTW, you will probably also run into a number of SDK version issues as well.